# Automapper ProjectTo and JSON column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have some simple models in EF Core (with a Postgres backend using Npgsql).

```
public class Test : Model
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public TestInfo Info { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestInfo
{
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Counts { get; set; } 
}

public class TestDTO
{
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string InfoName{ get; set; }
    public int[] Counts { get; set; } 
}
```

The EF Core config and Autommaper profile are

```
 public class TestConfig
    {
        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Test> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
            builder.Property(s => s.Info)
                .HasConversion(
                    v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                    v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestInfo>(v)
                )
                .HasColumnType("jsonb");
            builder.HasIndex(s => s.Info)
                .HasMethod("gin")
                .HasOperators("jsonb_ops");
        }
    }
    
public class TestProfile : Profile
{
    public TestProfile()
    {
         CreateMap<Test, TestDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.InfoName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Info.Name))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Info.Tags))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Counts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Info.Counts))
                .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I have been trying to use Automapper's ProjectTo to query but unable to figure out how to make it work. The below controller code throws coercion errors

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/test/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTest([FromRoute (Name = "id")][Required]string id)
{ 
   var t = await _mapper.ProjectTo<TestDTO>(
      _context.Tests.Where(s => s.Id == id)
   )
   .ToListAsync();
   return Ok(t); 
}
```

Errors (there is another error from System.String to System.string[] for Tags but I left out for brevity)

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Int32[]'.
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow(ExpressionType coercionType, Expression expression, Type convertToType)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression expression, Type type, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression expression, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.CreateGetValueExpression(ParameterExpression dbDataReader, Int32 index, Boolean nullable, RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping, Type type, IPropertyBase property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes, Func`2 elementVisitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache, LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at dms_apis.Controllers.OrganisationController.GetTest(String id) in /home/viet/src/dms-apis/Controllers/OrganisationController.cs:line 62
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I tried manual mapping using `Select` in the controller and that appears to work but ProjectTo seems to be much nicer

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/test/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTest([FromRoute (Name = "id")][Required]string id)
{ 
   var t = _context.Tests
           .Select(s => new TestDTO{
               Id = s.Id,
               Name = s.Info.Name
            })
            .Where(s => s.Id == id)
            .ToList();

   return Ok(t); 
}
```

What is the correct way to use ProjectTo in this case? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `ProjectTo` works with server evaluation, your query does client evaluation to work with `JsonConvert`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu can you please provide a bit more detail? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the page. But I am still not sure how it helps resolve my questions. If I remove `Tags` and `Counts`, things work fine. It appears to be that ProjectTo, in my code, doesn't know how to do the conversion like _mapper.Map() knows. In other words, if I just query without using ProjectTo and then do mapping on client side using _mapper.Map, things work fine.

Comment: I think you made things difficult for yourself by mixing things. If you drop the converter and just use `Map`, everything is fine, or alternatively, use only EF for conversions.

Comment: I dropped the converter and was still unable to use ProjectTo.

Comment: Sometimes I do not understand people. Simple `Select` do the job. But instead of that they install third-party library and spend hours in configuring one-time operation.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I didnt ask about whether I should use Automapper. I have use cases involving generics and having ProjectTo is much nicer to work with than manual selects.

Comment: It is not nicer, it is a way to get hidden errors after refactoring. Also ProjectTo adds additional CPU and memory usage when building ExpressionTree. Nevermind, just thoughts.

Comment: Configuration validation prevents such errors. And a `Select` will build an expression tree too :) That's not to say that `ProjectTo` is free.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible. Your query does client evaluation with JsonConvert while ProjectTo works with server evaluation.

Since EF Core 7 there is a JSON columns feature but this does not work with Automapper and ProjectTo. The error I get is similar to:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'JsonQueryExpression(i.ChildJsons, $)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

A workaround is to split the querying and the mapping when there is a JSON column.

AutoMapper Issue: [ProjectTo fails to work with EF Core 7 JSON columns](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4211)

AutoMapper Discussion: [ProjectTo fails to work with EF Core 7 JSON columns](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/4251)

Recent efcore fix:
[Remove initial $ PathSegment from JsonScalarExpression/JsonQueryExpression](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30747)

Comment: Are you sure it's about https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30747? They fixed it already, I've tested it on the latest daily build, but this bug still remains.

Comment: No. It seemed somewhat related looking at the error. Thanks for trying with the latest build!

Comment: I have reported the bug https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30830